# How to write inside a rectangle using memoir

Tags: memoir

I would like to print this book I am editing and it requires to have this specific information inside a rectangle...

How should I do it?

I have tried to create a table with lines on its borders, but I can not get `\vline` to work fine so it results in a table with only horizontal lines because `\hline` works fine.

[image]

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{|p{8cm}|} \hline A lot of text \\ \hline \end{tabular}`?

Comment: Is the problem how to draw a box around some text?

Comment: Wow! That was fast and simple.@TorbjørnT.
Thanks man, worked so far.

Comment: Yes @Ignasi....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While waiting for more information, a possible solution could be:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[sharp corners, notitle, colback=white]
Páginas: 316

\begin{enumerate}
\item Parapsicológica
\end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]